# In Cocos2D how do I detect that finger is being held down?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I know the `- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)`event method but was wondering how I constantly do something, such as move a sprite, while a finger is down?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it like Gajet or if your motion is constant you can schedule your actions. So assume you have this move method:

```
-(void)moveSprite:(ccTime) dt {

  // move your sprite here by small increments
}
```

And then in `ccTouchBegan:` method you mentioned, you schedule the move method `[self schedule:@selector(moveSprite:)]` and in `ccTouchEnded` you unschedule `[self unschedule:@selector(moveSprite:)]` this will stop the motion when you end your touch... Hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

you just have to set a boolean as true when `ccTouchBegan` is called and when `ccTouchEnd` is called set is as false, then when `ccTouchMove` event is called you only have to check weather your flag is true or not.

Comment: Yes, I tried this with a "while" statement, and it just crashed my app. May have just been my code though.

Comment: you should place any whiles in your code, you have to schedule update for you layer and the check your flag inside update function!

Answer (score 2):

Implement the appropriate [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) subclass. You'll be sent either a begin or a changed or an ended event - and may act accordingly.